# Centered square chessboard using GridView

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, border

It seems like this has been asked a lot of times and I've read so many questions and their answers but none of them would fit to my problem:

My situation:

- In my Activity, below a bunch of other stuff, you should see a chessboard. For small/short smartphones it's possible that the remaining space for the chessboard (which is a square) is not too much. Therefore I cannot simply say that the size of the chessboard is determined by the remaining width. If the remaining height is lower then the height determines the size.
- The number of squares varies within the game. The chessboard will always be a square but it's dimension varies from 3x3 to 8x8.
- I want my chessboard, which is implemented by using a GridView, to have a black border (circa 2pd).
- It would be nice if the squares of the chessboard could be real squares. But I want the size of the chessboard to be fix even if the number of columns varies. Therefore I cannot have a constant border thickness and squares that are real squares since the size of the chessboard (minus the border thickness) is not guaranteed to be divisible by the number of columns.

I see two possible solutions to handle this but I can't get them working:

1. To have a nice square chessboard, I use the follwing xml:

   `<GridView
       android:id="@+id/chessboard_gridview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:padding="2dp"
       android:layout_margin="10dp"
       android:background="@color/black"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:gravity="center" >
   </GridView>`

   and in `onCreate()` the following code in my activity:

   ```
   gridView.setNumColumns(board.getColumns());
   gridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){

       @Override
       public void onGlobalLayout() {

           int size = Math.min(gridView.getWidth(), gridView.getHeight());

           ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
           params.width = size;
           params.height = size;
           gridView.setLayoutParams(params);

           gridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
       }});
   ```

   And in order to have perfect squares as squares I found the following solution for ImageViews which are used by my custom Adapter:

   ```
   public class SquareView extends ImageView{

       public SquareView(Context context){
           super(context);
       }

       @Override
       public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
           super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
       }
   }
   ```

   But if I have a look at the result I can see that the border line thickness varies because the chessboard with is not divisible by the number of columns:

   [image: border line varies in thickness]

   I'm OK with that IF I somehow manage to have all squares centered in the GridView. Then the border is thicker than 2dp and it's possible that one side is one pixel thicker than the other, but I don't care.

   QUESTION: How can I center the squares such that the border thickness does not vary to that extend?
2. Another approach would be to have a nice border of exactly 2 dp but the squares wouldn't really be squares. The remaining space that makes the border thicker on the right and at the bottom could be more or less equally distributed over the squares. For example: if there are 3 remaining pixels, make the 2., 4. and 6. column each one pixel wider and the 2., 4. and 6. row higher.

   QUESTION: How can I use all the GridView space perfectly for my squares even if that means that my squares aren't real squares anymore but some are slightly wider or higher?

   I had thought that the GridView does stretch them automatically but if I use a simple ImageView and not my SquareView for the squares I have a black chessboard if I do not set the size of each square on my own. If I do set a square size for the squares manually I get different wrong results for all the stretchModes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question quite a while ago and decided to finally write how I solved my problem then. In the end I didn't care that the chessboard size might vary when changing the number of rows and columns. Please note that there might be a more up-to-date answer. This is a solution that worked for me in 2015.

My GridView:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/chessboard_gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="2dp">
</GridView>
```

initialized in an Activity's `onCreate`:

```
this.gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.chessboard_gridview);
```

The same Activity uses a custom Adapter for the chessboard:

```
ChessboardViewAdapter adapter = new ChessboardViewAdapter(numRows, numCols, ...);       
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The `ChessboardViewAdapter` then (among other things) determines the proper size for the squares. Note that the `SquareView` is a custom class that does not override `onMeasure` anymore like in the code from my original question.

```
public class ChessboardViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ...
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View view = convertView;
        if(view == null){
            view = new SquareView(context);
        }

        // Adjust each square's size to look like a square
        int parentPadding = 2 * parent.getPaddingTop(); // equal paddings
        int newSize = (parent.getWidth() - parentPadding) / this.columns;
        view.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(newSize, newSize));
        view.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10); // hard coded offsets for the black border
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I am reading you problem right. The problem could be due to size is not equally divisible by board.getColumns. So we can choose a newSize that would be equally divisible for the given board columns.

```
gridView.setNumColumns(board.getColumns());
gridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    int size = Math.min(gridView.getWidth(), gridView.getHeight());
    int newsize = (size/board.getColumns()) * board.getColumns(); // computing new size

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = gridView.getLayoutParams();
    params.width = newsize; //assigning new size
    params.height = newsize; //assigning new size
    gridView.setLayoutParams(params);

    gridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
}});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I've already written that I know that the problem is due to the size not being equally divisible by the number of columns. And I said that I want my chessboard size to be fix.

Comment: Then assign padding = (size-newsize)/2

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: I've thought about it but I think, changing the padding dynamically could result in a lot of trouble. If I change the generell padding, this won't fix anything; if I change the top, bottom, etc. separately and with different values I mess things up because I have to use negative paddings.